# Using ACRA with Haxe

Tags: android, android-manifest, cross-compiling, haxe, acra

For a Haxe project that cross-compiles to Android, how do you add ACRA functionality?  `haxelib run lime build "Project.xml" android -release -Dfdb` takes Haxe code and gives you an APK, so how can you inject [the requisite .jar file, Java code, and AndroidManifest.xml tags](http://www.acra.ch/) at the right moment during the build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy AndroidManifest.xml and GameActivity.java, modify and use modified files instead of original.
Example of such usage could be found [here](http://player03.com/2014/08/14/template-basics/)

Comment: Thank you, this definitely has me on the right path!  However, I don't think I should override the GameActivity.java template, because the ACRA docs say to make a new Application-derived, not Activity-derived class.